# Issue with creating sensor overlay based on dbIDs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im trying to create something similar as the IoT demo from autodesk (https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=58adee163e6f342cf1e92dae)
However instead of knowing the coordinates of each sensor im trying to use the dbId of assets to determine the position. Even though with the use of different examples I dont seem to be able to align the overlay properly. The point does not seem to match the selection I made. The red dot is the overlay and the asset from what I got the position from is selected.

[example image](https://ibb.co/JnqdQCD)

```
public createPoint() {
  const viewer = this.viewer;

  viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(4295, (frag) => {
    const renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, frag);

    const position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.setFromMatrixPosition( renderProxy.matrixWorld );

    const worldToClient = viewer.worldToClient(position);

    const element = <HTMLElement>document.getElementsByClassName('bimSensorNode-1')[0];
    element.style.top = worldToClient.y + 'px';
    element.style.left = worldToClient.x + 'px';

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this blog post on how to add "3d-markup-icons-and-info-card":

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card

it has source-code on GitHub, and a helper technique to cheaply identify an exact x,y,z point here:

https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/issues/2

Say you want to get an x,y,z point on the edge of a table.  Using your mouse, ALT-click on the edge-of the table... this will set a green pivot point.  Now use this code to retrieve the x,y,z point...

`NOP_VIEWER.getCamera().pivot;`

Let me know if that helps.
Cheers
Michael

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.

I would actually like to remove the step where people define where the sensor is. In our system we know what sensors are linked to what asset. Thats why find the asset and try to get the position in the model from. However for some assets this seems to be acting odd and the point is not on the model at all but away from it. 


[Correct](https://ibb.co/SQLwFBj)

[Incorrect](https://ibb.co/T1519NL)

Comment: In a past project I was making up a position by analyzing the geometry. See the code [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/Pier9.IoT/blob/master/www/js/IoTTools.js#L440)

Comment: @cyrille , That looks like what i'm looking for. The bouding box approach seems to work and produces the correct result.

Thanks both for the replies!